# Обновление версии PIP

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pycharm, pip

Пытаюсь обновить pip на ubuntu:

(test) test@Ubuntu1604-001:~$ pip install --upgrade pip

Получаю:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./test/lib/python3.6/site-packages (21.3.1)
```

Но pycharm говорит, что есть версия 22.0.3

В среде выдает ошибку:

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '*****блаблабла/bin/python3'.
```

Как обновить? И связана ли эта ошибка с тем, что я и некоторые другие библиотеки обновить не могу. Например Django на версию 4.0.3

Comment: У вас просто слишком старая версия Python

Comment: таким образом, обновив python можно будет обновить pip и другие библиотеки?

Comment: Обновите всю систему целиком, поддержка Ubuntu 16.04 закончилась ещё год назад